# Regex expression to find word string containing one or more instances of a specific substring

Tags: regex, search, nlp, regular-language

I am trying to write a regex for a set of words. I want to select only the words that have one or more repetition of a substring.

For instance, among the following words:

> **banana** **baba** nano **nana** nanna

I only want to select words banana, baba, nana and do **NOT** want to select nano and nanna. What I am trying to find here are words that contains **ba** or **na** one or more times and not the words that contains anything other than one or more instances of **ba** or **na**. Therefore, nanna shouldn't be selected because it contains an extra **n** between the two **na**'s.

I tried quite a few regex but couldn't find the exact results. 
So far this is the regex where I am stuck at.

> \w+(ba|na)

This selects nanna as well which I don't want. I am new to regex and have tried quite a few examples and tutorials, and also looked around for a while.

P.S I am using [this website](https://regexr.com/)  to test my regex.

Comment: Try [`\w*([bn]a)\1+\w*`](https://regex101.com/r/dn3BOd/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b(?:[bn]a)+\b`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iFRfBC/1

Explanation:

`\b` - Matches a "word border", preventing additional letters from preceding (or following, at the end of the pattern) the match.

`(?: ... )+` - A (non-capturing) group, quantified one or more times.

`[bn]a` - A literal `b` or `n`, followed by an `a`.

Comment: So just wanted to confirm. Did you use the (?:.....) to group the results together right?

Comment: The group is needed for the `+` quantifier to work as expected here, otherwise it would only act on the `a` alone.

Comment: Really appreciate your explanation Austin. :)